# Pull results into Excel from database

Tags: vba, excel

I can't get this code to work. The first time I ran it, it prompted me for my password and the macro completes each time, but it is not pulling the result into `sheet1`. What can I do here?

```
Sub Update()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select
    Dim strStDt As String
    Dim strEnDt As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    strStDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lookup").Range("B6").Value
    strEnDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lookup").Range("B5").Value

    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT tkt.cntry_istto"
    strSQL = strSQL & ",tkt.pod"

    strSQL = strSQL & " FROM INTGY.GRUIP tkt"

    strSQL = strSQL & " Where tky.year_month_nbr between " & strStDt & " and " & strEnDt


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Select

    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1).ODBCConnection

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .Connection = "ODBC;DSN=#EDXX;UID=;;DATABASE=INTGY; AUTHENTICATION=;"
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .SourceDataFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
        .Refresh

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify that strSQL is being entered correctly into your query? Put `Msgbox strSQL` before `With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1).ODBCConnection` and make sure it appears as expected.

Also, all of this:

```
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT tkt.cntry_istto"
strSQL = strSQL & ",tkt.pod"

strSQL = strSQL & " FROM INTGY.GRUIP tkt"

strSQL = strSQL & " Where tky.year_month_nbr between " & strStDt & " and " & strEnDt
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
strSQL = "SELECT tkt.cntry_istto,tkt.pod FROM INTGY.GRUIP tkt Where tky.year_month_nbr between " & strStDt & " and " & strEnDt
```

Comment: A excel box poped up with my SQL. Does that mean it is working? If it is how can I put the results in sheet1. thanks for your help

Comment: That just gives you an opportunity to check the SQL and make sure it is being input properly - that there are no errors with it. I do not know how to paste SQL results to Excel, you'll have to research that yourself, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ADO connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819) to retrieve a recordset and then use [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) to copy to worksheet range (specifying only the upper left cell).

Also, I am unaware of the database but pay attention to your dates which must be enclosed with either single quotes (for most databases) or if using MS Access enclose with `#` instead of quotes.

```
Dim conn As Object 
Dim rst As Object
Dim strSQL As String, strStDt As String, strEnDt As String

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strStDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lookup").Range("B6")
strEnDt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("lookup").Range("B5")

strSQL = "SELECT tkt.cntry_istto, tkt.pod"
strSQL = strSQL & " FROM INTGY.GRUIP tkt"
strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE tkt.year_month_nbr"
strSQL = strSQL & " BETWEEN '" & strStDt & "' and '" & strEnDt & "'

conn.Open "DSN=#EDXX"
rst.Open strSQL, conn

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordest rst
rst.Close

Set rst = Nothing 
Set conn = Nothing
```